# Why is my Laravel Eloquent accessor not showing up in the response?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5, accessor

I have a Model `Review` that has a unix timestamp as 1 of it's attributes (table columns).

I use 2 [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) inside this model:

```php
public function getReviewDateAttribute($value)
{
    return strftime('%A %e %B %Y', $value);
}

public function getReviewDateIsoAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::createFromTimestamp($this->review_date)->toDateTimeString();
}
```

`getReviewDateAttribute` works as expected and shows up in the collection of models when I write a query.

However `getReviewDateIsoAttribute` does not. What could be the reason for this?

A subquestion: If I use the same attribute in both functions, how can I use the original format as input value?

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should be adding it to the `$appends` array. It isn't spinning through all available methods looking for `getXXXXXAttribute`. The other one is used because it is an accessor for an actual attribute, this one is not an actual attribute.

```
class YourModel ....
{
     protected $appends = ['review_date_iso'];
     ...
}
```

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Eloquent - Serialization - Appending Values to JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Comment: To automatically append accessors to response, you can use https://github.com/topclaudy/eloquent-auto-append

Comment: thanks very much! I spent many hours to use accessors in vue components!

Comment: Does this work with methods from traits? Because I moved isAdmin() to a trait

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because `ReviewDateIso` is not an actual column and therefore will not show up in the model collections...you can access it directly by calling the method directly

```
$model->getReviewDateIsoAttribute()
```

According to the docs accessors a ways of changing the value of a column before it is returned to the method that queried it.

If you want it to show up when you call the collection as Json append it to the output with

```
protected $appends = ['name_of_attribute'];
```

Comment: I understand what you try to say, but Laravel `accessors` are "magic" functions that create attributes on the fly, hence this still should work. Please take a look at the documentation's `getFullNameAttribute` example.

Comment: It could also have something to do with the way your query is structures, here's a link to an issue like that 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/custom-accessor-not-working-anymore

Answer (score 1):

I tried queries in tinker and with dd method. So I got confused since I cant view my new accessor in the attribute list.

I thought I missed something. Then later I noticed appended attributes are shown separately when we dd the query result than the usual attribute JSON.

I lost time thinking my accessor is not working. Its just I`m not checking in the right way or right place. So I``m attaching the following image, if anyone gets stuck on accessors like me, this might help them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In fact it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are going to display anything in Blade for example, you can use whenever you want `$object->review_date_iso` to get this attribute value.

However if you are returning Json responses (for example API), you need to tell Eloquent model to append extra fields to your model when transforming to JSON format.

You probably have `review_date` attribute in your model (this is the column in database I suppose) but you don't have `review_date_iso` in your table in database, so in your model you need to use:

```
protected $appends = ['review_date_iso'];
```

but you don't have to include here `review_date` because it's already in your table in database and your accessor will be automatically fired.